# Programs launch to wrong display

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, launcher

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and have the desktop spread across two displays:

[image: Laptop screen on the left, main monitor on the right]

Sometimes when I start a program from the launcher on the BenQ display, the window will open on the laptop display. This isn't such a problem as I can just drag the window back onto the main display, but it is slightly irritating.

Is there a way to make programs always launch to the main display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Compiz tool:

> sudo apt-get install compiz compiz-plugins

Find it in Unity dash by typing:

> ccsm

and open it.

Find "Window Placement" options down below. Play with options, but as far as I remember, you can switch on something like "Place window in cursor active window".

Also, it can make Unity remember the previous window position, so that would also be useful.